# error : no such device:.... Entering rescue mode... grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Ok so I installed Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 7 last year. But I found out I never used it so I decided to wipe the Ubuntu drive from Windows. Next startup I got this error, note the grub partition has been wiped and I have no way to booting into Win 7 now cuz of this grub rescue error. I have a Kali Linux live USB, so I can boot and do some changes (although this is technically not a Ubuntu live USB)

Edit: I can't boot into neither Windows or Ubuntu (It's deleted) now, so commands to run in Ubuntu won't work for me. And btw the grub files are gone.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: The thing is I can't boot into windows or Linux (cuz it's deleted?) So I can't try that. The only things I can do are through the live usb

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/repair-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/) shows how to repair your Windows bootloader (MBR) from Ubuntu dual boot or Ubuntu live DVD/USB. This can be useful if you don't have a Windows DVD on hand.

Boot into your Ubuntu operating system. When you're in Ubuntu, open the terminal and follow the below steps.

1. Run this command to check your disk:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   The output tells you the disk information:

   ```
   Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x016c8108

   Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
   /dev/sda1 * 63 39054014 19526976 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   ```
2. Now run these commands to install syslinux, which is a suite of lightweight IBM PC MBR bootloaders for starting up computers with the Linux kernel.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install syslinux
   ```
3. Once installed, you can fix your Windows bootloader by running the below command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
   ```

Comment: If you want an upvoted answer, copy/paste the text from this [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tGCQn8HgV5/) link (it's the same as your answer here) as an answer to [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/) and I'll upvote it.